# Style One Column Based on Another Column using DT in R

Tags: r, dt

The below code create a dataframe with variable `test1_score` and `test2_score`. I need to change background of `test2_score` if it is more than `test1_score`.

Below is the code to create the create the dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = 1:10,
  name = c("Bob", "Ashley", "James", "David", "Jenny", 
           "Hans", "Leo", "John", "Emily", "Lee"), 
  age = c(28, 27, 30, 28, 29, 29, 27, 27, 31, 30),
  grade = c("C", "A", "A", "C", "B", "B", "B", "A", "C", "C"),
  test1_score = c(8.9, 9.5, 9.6, 8.9, 9.1, 9.3, 9.3, 9.9, 8.5, 8.6),
  test2_score = c(9.1, 9.1, 9.2, 9.1, 8.9, 8.5, 9.2, 9.3, 9.1, 8.8),
  final_score = c(9, 9.3, 9.4, 9, 9, 8.9, 9.25, 9.6, 8.8, 8.7),
  registered = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I am using `DT` for formating tables.
Used the below code but getting blank table as output.

```
datatable(df) %>%
  DT::formatStyle(columns = "test2_score", valueColumns = "test1_score", 
  backgroundColor = styleInterval("test1_score", c('gray', 'yellow')))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
library(DT)
df <- data.frame(
  id = 1:10,
  name = c("Bob", "Ashley", "James", "David", "Jenny", 
           "Hans", "Leo", "John", "Emily", "Lee"), 
  age = c(28, 27, 30, 28, 29, 29, 27, 27, 31, 30),
  grade = c("C", "A", "A", "C", "B", "B", "B", "A", "C", "C"),
  test1_score = c(8.9, 9.5, 9.6, 8.9, 9.1, 9.3, 9.3, 9.9, 8.5, 8.6),
  test2_score = c(9.1, 9.1, 9.2, 9.1, 8.9, 8.5, 9.2, 9.3, 9.1, 8.8),
  final_score = c(9, 9.3, 9.4, 9, 9, 8.9, 9.25, 9.6, 8.8, 8.7),
  registered = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
colors <- with(df, ifelse(test1_score > test2_score, "pink", "blue"))
rgbcolors <- apply(grDevices::col2rgb(colors), 2, 
                   function(rgb) sprintf("rgb(%s)", paste(rgb, collapse=",")))
columns <- c(5,6) # columns test1_score and test2_score
jscode <- 
  paste("function(row, data, index) {",  
        sprintf("var colors=%s;\n%s", 
                sprintf("[%s]", 
                        paste(sprintf("'%s'", rgbcolors), collapse=", ")), 
                paste(sprintf("$(this.api().cell(index, %s).node()).css('background-color', colors[index]);", 
                              columns), collapse="\n")), 
        "}", sep="\n")

datatable(df, escape=FALSE, 
          options = list(rowCallback=JS(jscode)))
```

[image]

Is it the result you expect ?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a workaround you can use

```
#Define a new column for testing
df$Result <- factor(ifelse(df$test2_score > df$test1_score,'More','Not More'),
                    levels=c('More','Not More'))

datatable(df,options = list(columnDefs = list(list(visible=FALSE, targets=c(9))))) %>% #Hide Result using visible=F
   formatStyle('test2_score', valueColumns = 'Result', target = c('cell'),
                backgroundColor = styleEqual(unique(df$Result),  c('gray', 'yellow')))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a cleaner solution than the other one I gave (which is quite unreadable).

```
datatable(df, 
          options=list(initComplete = JS(
          "function(settings) {
            var table = settings.oInstance.api();
            for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
              var cell1 = table.cell(i,5);
              var cell2 = table.cell(i,6);
              if(cell1.data() > cell2.data()){
                cell1.node().style.backgroundColor='pink';
              }else{
                cell1.node().style.backgroundColor='blue';
              }
            }
          }")))
```